# error while installing Multinest on Ubuntu 16.04:

Tags: mpi, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to install MultiNest and PyMultiNest on Ubutnu 16.04. I have OpenMPI installed and can successfully run programs with it. However, during the installation of MultiNest, during the final 'make' step, I get this:

`kevin@kevin-VirtualBox:~/MultiNest/build$ make
Scanning dependencies of target multinest_static
[  1%] Building Fortran object src/CMakeFiles/multinest_static.dir/utils.f90.o
[  2%] Building Fortran object src/CMakeFiles/multinest_static.dir/utils1.f90.o
[  4%] Building Fortran object src/CMakeFiles/multinest_static.dir/kmeans_clstr.f90.o
[  5%] Building Fortran object src/CMakeFiles/multinest_static.dir/xmeans_clstr.f90.o
[  7%] Building Fortran object src/CMakeFiles/multinest_static.dir/posterior.F90.o
[  8%] Building Fortran object src/CMakeFiles/multinest_static.dir/priors.f90.o
[ 10%] Building Fortran object src/CMakeFiles/multinest_static.dir/nested.F90.o
[ 11%] Building Fortran object src/CMakeFiles/multinest_static.dir/cwrapper.f90.o
[ 12%] Linking Fortran static library ../../lib/libmultinest.a
[ 12%] Built target multinest_static
Scanning dependencies of target multinest_shared
[ 14%] Building Fortran object src/CMakeFiles/multinest_shared.dir/utils.f90.o
[ 15%] Building Fortran object src/CMakeFiles/multinest_shared.dir/utils1.f90.o
[ 17%] Building Fortran object src/CMakeFiles/multinest_shared.dir/kmeans_clstr.f90.o
[ 18%] Building Fortran object src/CMakeFiles/multinest_shared.dir/xmeans_clstr.f90.o
[ 20%] Building Fortran object src/CMakeFiles/multinest_shared.dir/posterior.F90.o
[ 21%] Building Fortran object src/CMakeFiles/multinest_shared.dir/priors.f90.o
[ 22%] Building Fortran object src/CMakeFiles/multinest_shared.dir/nested.F90.o
[ 24%] Building Fortran object src/CMakeFiles/multinest_shared.dir/cwrapper.f90.o
[ 25%] Linking Fortran shared library ../../lib/libmultinest.so
[ 25%] Built target multinest_shared
Scanning dependencies of target multinest_mpi_static
[ 27%] Building Fortran object src/CMakeFiles/multinest_mpi_static.dir/utils.f90.o
[ 28%] Building Fortran object src/CMakeFiles/multinest_mpi_static.dir/utils1.f90.o
[ 30%] Building Fortran object src/CMakeFiles/multinest_mpi_static.dir/kmeans_clstr.f90.o
[ 31%] Building Fortran object src/CMakeFiles/multinest_mpi_static.dir/xmeans_clstr.f90.o
[ 32%] Building Fortran object src/CMakeFiles/multinest_mpi_static.dir/posterior.F90.o
[ 34%] Building Fortran object src/CMakeFiles/multinest_mpi_static.dir/priors.f90.o
[ 35%] Building Fortran object src/CMakeFiles/multinest_mpi_static.dir/nested.F90.o
mpif.h:54: Error: Can't open included file 'mpif-config.h'
src/CMakeFiles/multinest_mpi_static.dir/build.make:206: recipe for target 'src/CMakeFiles/multinest_mpi_static.dir/nested.F90.o' failed
make[3]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/multinest_mpi_static.dir/nested.F90.o] Error 1
src/CMakeFiles/multinest_mpi_static.dir/build.make:222: recipe for target 'src/CMakeFiles/multinest_mpi_static.dir/nested.F90.o.provides' failed
make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/multinest_mpi_static.dir/nested.F90.o.provides] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:190: recipe for target 'src/CMakeFiles/multinest_mpi_static.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/multinest_mpi_static.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:127: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2`

Any guidance or insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you got mpif90 correctly installed? What happens when you do 

    `mpif90 --showme:compile` and  `mpif90 --showme:link` and `locate mpif-config.h`

Comment: `kevin@kevin-VirtualBox:~/MultiNest/build$ mpif90 --showme:compile
-I/usr/lib/openmpi/include -pthread -I/usr/lib/openmpi/lib
kevin@kevin-VirtualBox:~/MultiNest/build$ mpif90 --showme:link
-pthread -I/usr/lib/openmpi/lib -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/usr/lib/openmpi/lib -Wl,--enable-new-dtags -L/usr/lib/openmpi/lib -lmpi_usempif08 -lmpi_usempi_ignore_tkr -lmpi_mpifh -lmpi
kevin@kevin-VirtualBox:~/MultiNest/build$ locate mpif-config.h
/home/kevin/Downloads/openmpi-3.0.0/ompi/include/mpif-config.h
/home/kevin/Downloads/openmpi-3.0.0/ompi/include/mpif-config.h.in
`

Comment: what if you `dpkg -L libopenmpi-dev | grep include/mpif` ? the file should be in `/usr/lib/openmpi/include/mpif-config.h`

Comment: OK, so your `mpi-config.h` isn't in `/usr/lib/openmpi/include`, as expected by mpif90. Something is wrong with your installation. Probably you installed openmpi locally, such that headers weren't placed in `/usr/`

Comment: an other possible explanation is your app is not using the wrappers in `/usr/lib/openmpi/bin`. `make V=1 src/CMakeFiles/multinest_mpi_static.dir/nested.F90.o` should help you figure out what is going on.

Comment: doing `dpkg -L ... ` reveals that the file is indeed in `/usr/lib/openmpi/include/mpif-config.h`.  Not sure why it didn't indicate so in the "locate" command above. I then tried `make V=1 src/CMakeFiles/multinest_mpi_static.dir/nested.F90.o`, and got this result: `make: *** No rule to make target 'src/CMakeFiles/multinest_mpi_static.dir/nested.F90.o'.  Stop.`